# Animate html text via css

Tags: html, css

I want to create a text animation, in which the text is automatically and constantly moving from one side to the other side of the website. Like a text would do on a ticker display. Does anybody know about a simple css code I can use to animate the text in this way?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried it out with the  tag, but it lags a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>css animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="anim">Hello world!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.anim {
    animation: move 2s infinite;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

.anim {
    animation: move 5s infinite;
    position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes move {
    0%   {left:100%;}
    50%  {left: 0px;}
    100% { opacity:0;}
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/djalms/pen/GRGmYoZ

Comment: Thank you Noel for your quick answer! I mispoke when I said from one side to the other. What I am actually talking about is the effect that you get, when you create the following object <marquee>Hello World</marquee>. You'll see the text coming from the right side, moving to the left, disappearing and then reappearing from the right side and so son. Do you know how to create that effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <link
      rel="apple-touch-icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-5ae1a0698dcc2402e9712f7d01ed509a57814f994c660df9f7a952f3060705ee.png"
    />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="CodePen" />

    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      type="image/x-icon"
      href="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-aec34940fbc1a6e787974dcd360f2c6b63348d4b1f4e06c77743096d55480f33.ico"
    />

    <link
      rel="mask-icon"
      type="image/x-icon"
      href="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-8f3771b1072e3c38bd662872f6b673a722f4b3ca2421637d5596661b4e2132cc.svg"
      color="#111"
    />

    <title>CodePen - Wave Text</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />

    <style>
      .container {
        max-width: 960px;
      }

      body {
        background-color: #fafafa;
      }

      .widthset {
        width: 16.5%;
      }

      .heading-style {
        font-family: "Righteous", cursive;
        font-size: 205px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 2px rgba(6, 188, 209, 0.2);
        background: #ffffff;
        mix-blend-mode: screen;
        padding-top: 190px;
      }

      @media (min-width: 1200px) .container,
        .container-lg,
        .container-md,
        .container-sm,
        .container-xl {
        max-width: 1140px;
      }

      @media (min-width: 992px) .container,
        .container-lg,
        .container-md,
        .container-sm {
        max-width: 960px;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) .container, .container-md, .container-sm {
        max-width: 720px;
      }

      @media (min-width: 576px) .container, .container-sm {
        max-width: 540px;
      }

      @media (min-width: 1200px) .container {
        max-width: 1140px;
      }

      @media (min-width: 992px) .container {
        max-width: 960px;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) .container {
        max-width: 720px;
      }

      @media (min-width: 576px) .container {
        max-width: 540px;
      }

      .shadow {
        box-shadow: 0px 18px 39.1px 6.9px rgba(224, 241, 255, 0.34) !important;
      }

      .card {
        border: 0;
      }

      .mt-15 {
        margin-top: 15%;
      }

      .progress-wrapper {
        height: 240px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .wave {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .card-body {
        -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding: 1.25rem;
      }

      .card-title {
        margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
      }

      .list-unstyled {
        padding-left: 0;
        list-style: none;
      }

      .card {
        position: relative;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-width: 0;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-clip: border-box;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .wave::before,
      .wave::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 470px;
        height: 390px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 55%;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
        border-radius: 70%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0);
        transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0);
        -webkit-animation: rotate 6s linear infinite;
        animation: rotate 6s linear infinite;
        z-index: 10;
      }

      .wave::after {
        border-radius: 30%;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0);
        transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0);
        -webkit-animation: rotate 10s linear -5s infinite;
        animation: rotate 10s linear -5s infinite;
        z-index: 20;
      }

      @keyframes rotate {
        50% {
          transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(180deg);
        }

        100% {
          transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(360deg);
        }
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .heading-style {
          font-family: "Righteous", cursive;
          font-size: 156px;
        }

        .progress-wrapper {
          height: 209px;
        }
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
        .heading-style {
          font-family: "Righteous", cursive;
          font-size: 65px;
        }

        .progress-wrapper {
          height: 148px;
        }

        .wave::before,
        .wave::after {
          width: 490px;
          height: 331px;
        }
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      window.console = window.console || function (t) {};
    </script>

    <script>
      if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
        window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body translate="no">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szLmLFsisbY" target="_blank">
      <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row mt-15">
            <div class="text-center widthset">
              <div
                class="position-relative rounded-top progress-wrapper"
                style="
                  background-image: linear-gradient(
                    to bottom,
                    #f8e739,
                    #f1d42d,
                    #eac222,
                    #e1b019,
                    #d89e10
                  );
                "
              >
                <div class="wave" style="bottom: 80%">
                  <h1 class="heading-style">H</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center widthset">
              <div
                class="position-relative rounded-top progress-wrapper"
                style="
                  background-image: linear-gradient(
                    to bottom,
                    #d89e10,
                    #e28f00,
                    #ec7f00,
                    #f66b00,
                    #ff5200
                  );
                "
              >
                <div class="wave" style="bottom: 80%">
                  <h1 class="heading-style">E</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center widthset">
              <div
                class="position-relative rounded-top progress-wrapper"
                style="
                  background-image: linear-gradient(
                    to bottom,
                    #e2130b,
                    #e1110c,
                    #e00f0d,
                    #df0c0d,
                    #de090e
                  );
                "
              >
                <div class="wave" style="bottom: 80%">
                  <h1 class="heading-style">L</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center widthset">
              <div
                class="position-relative rounded-top progress-wrapper"
                style="
                  background-image: linear-gradient(
                    to bottom,
                    #ce0061,
                    #d50079,
                    #d60094,
                    #d000b3,
                    #c115d4
                  );
                "
              >
                <div class="wave" style="bottom: 80%">
                  <h1 class="heading-style">L</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center widthset">
              <div
                class="position-relative rounded-top progress-wrapper"
                style="
                  background-image: linear-gradient(
                    to bottom,
                    #6a0ddc,
                    #5f0ddd,
                    #530edd,
                    #450fde,
                    #3210de
                  );
                "
              >
                <div class="wave" style="bottom: 80%">
                  <h1 class="heading-style">O</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).